# Error Google Drive Insert API: Operation timed out

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I have an error when calling Google Drive API v2 (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert):

```
$service->files->insert()
```

My script first upload file to server then upload file to Google Drive storage.
It works fine form small file, but if I try large file (90-100 MB) i got:

```
An error occurred: Operation timed out after 100000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received.
```

Is it a Google limit (doc: Maximum file size: 5120GB) or I need to set any PHP parameters ?
I use same code included in previous link and I tried to increase this params in php.ini:

- upload_max_filesize = 100M
- post_max_size = 100M
- max_execution_time = 300
- max_input_time = 300
- memory_limit = 1024M

The file is uploaded correctly on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with php, as I'm not familiar with it. But a similar problem was encountered while I was working on a .NET project.

The solution was to set the `Timeout` parameter of the Drive service object, like mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload):

> If you see this exception, consider manually increasing the `Timeout` property in the client used by your service object.

in C#, the code looked something like:

```
service.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(100);
```

I remember having to reference `System.Net.Http`.

Hope this would give you some insight and would help you fix it in php.

Comment: Thank you !! I solve increasing in Google_Config in google-api-php-client/src/Google/Config.php the "request_timeout_seconds" parameter.